# Passing a field symbol as changing parameter cause short dump. Why?

Tags: abap

Why does SAP try to be smarter than it has to be and produce short dump in the following case?

```
REPORT zzy.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF t_my_type,
        hierlevel TYPE i,
        groupname TYPE ktext,
        result    TYPE p LENGTH 9 DECIMALS 2,
      END OF t_my_type,
      tt_my_type TYPE HASHED TABLE OF t_my_type WITH UNIQUE KEY hierlevel groupname.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      change
        CHANGING
          cs_my_type TYPE t_my_type.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA:
      lt_my_table TYPE tt_my_type.

    INSERT VALUE #( hierlevel = 0 groupname = 'MY_GROUP' result = '0.0' ) INTO TABLE lt_my_table
      ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_my_type>).

    change(
      CHANGING
        cs_my_type = <fs_my_type>
    ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD change.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

There is nothing changed in the method `change` and yet in the description of the short dump I see

> Field `<FS_MY_TYPE>-HIERLEVEL` was to assigned a new value but this field is at least partly protected against changes.

It looks that SAP tries to be smarter than it should be. I would understand if the short dump was produced if I actually tried to change one of the key fields. Why is this designed that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just spotted that further description in the short dump has that

> The following are protected against changes:
>   - Access using field symbols if the field assigned using ASSIGN is
>   **partly** or completely protected (for example key components of internal
>   table of the type SORTED or HASHED TABLE).

A bit strange for me but looks like a design decision. Maybe it was technically hard to check only for the fields that are actually protected.

Answer (score 0):

When using `INSERT...ASSIGNING <fs_row>` syntax you should always be aware of restrictions that apply to the corresponding field symbol. According to SAP, [the same](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abapinsert_itab_result.htm) restrictions that exist in `READ TABLE ...ASSIGNING <fs_row>` are applied to `INSERT` construction as well. In particular, they are:

> As long as the field symbol points to the row, assignments to the
>   field symbol modify the row in the internal table. The following
>   limitations apply to modifying key fields of the primary and secondary
>   table key:
>
> - The key fields of the primary table key of sorted tables and hashed
>     tables **are read-only and must not be modified**. This would invalidate
>     internal table administration. Attempts to do this generally raise an
>     unhandleable exception.
>     **...**

The same restrictions are applied for inline declarations [as well](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abapread_table_outdesc.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_2@2@).
As we see in your code, you use implicit pass by reference declaration for parameters of your method. But pass by reference don't create any local data objects for parameters and [works with the actual parameters instead](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenpass_by_reference_glosry.htm), which requires them *to be writable*. This is the key to your question.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The key fields are not changed in any way by me. I have already posted my answer. It looks like it is simply a design decision. What was the reason of it stays however unclear to me.

Comment: Consider carefully _pass by reference_ definition.It doesn't matter you don't really change them inside method. As they are declared `CHANGING` compiler requires them to be writeable anyway.

Comment: Once again, irrelevant for this particular case. I know that I am passing by reference. The clue is that the key fields in the `change` method are **not** changed in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly, we can pass data reference as changed parameter and it works. System lets you change the non-key fields without error and throws a short dump for a key field change.

```
    REPORT zzy.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF t_my_type,
        hierlevel TYPE i,
        groupname TYPE ktext,
        result    TYPE p LENGTH 9 DECIMALS 2,
      END OF t_my_type,
      tt_my_type TYPE HASHED TABLE OF t_my_type WITH UNIQUE KEY hierlevel groupname.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      change
        CHANGING
          cs_my_type TYPE REF TO t_my_type.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA:
      lt_my_table TYPE tt_my_type.
    DATA ls_ref TYPE REF TO t_my_type.
    INSERT VALUE #( hierlevel = 0 groupname = 'MY_GROUP' result = '0.0' ) INTO TABLE lt_my_table
      ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_my_type>).

    GET REFERENCE OF <fs_my_type> INTO ls_ref.
    change(
      CHANGING
        cs_my_type = ls_ref
    ).

    write: | { <fs_my_type>-result }|.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD change.
*    cs_my_type->*-groupname = 'GRP2'.  "Short dump: Assignment error: Overwriting of a protected field.
    cs_my_type->*-result = '10.1'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```